# How do I set the runtime classpath in Eclipse 4.2?

Tags: eclipse

When I select Run Configurations from the Run menu I see no tab named Classpath as in previous versions of Eclipse. Where do I set the runtime classpath?

Comment: Yes, should have been a "no". Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Eclipse look at Project -> Properties for the project you want a runtime configuration. Choose Run/Debug settings and choose new or edit one you already have. When creating a New run/debug config make sure to choose Java Project. When the dialog box opens you will see a tab for classpath directives.

Comment: I see the seven tabs "Main", "Arguments", "Plug-ins", "Configuration", "Tracing", "Environment" and "Common". There is no classpath tab. Which version of Eclipse do you use?

Comment: Indigo R2, I also have Helios and Galileo and they both have the same option for providing a runtime classpath in the "Run/Debug Settings" box. It looks like you do not have either Java support installed in Eclipse or you are not in a Java project configuration.

Comment: Turns out that only Java projects have the Classpath tab whereas I'm working on an e4 plugin. I think I will make a plugin wrapper of the library I'm referring to instead.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this when developing a plugin for Eclipse - apparently the whole classpath business is slightly different in there.

See this [FAQ item](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_the_classpath_of_a_plug-in?) for more details