# How to run RMI Chat Application in JAVA in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, chat, rmi

I am developing a RMI Chat application in Java. I am trying to run simple RMI application in eclipse IDE. But it issues following problem. I know how to run it from command prompt and its running without any problem. If you could suggest me the ways to run RMI application in Eclipse IDE is really appreciated. Thank you!

Error:

```
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: examples.credit.CreditChecker
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: examples.credit.CreditChecker
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyInterfaces(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: error is saying clearly "ClassNotFound". Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: examples.credit.CreditChecker. check this class is available or not in your class path.

Comment: @kshitij, Thank you. Well, can you please tell me how can i configure class path. Besides, i did codebase path as suggested from the  error. But it didnt work out.

Comment: if your this class is in jar file then you just need to add that jar file in lib folder of your eclipse project. and if it class that made by you then you just need to put it in src folder of eclipse project.

Comment: you can check following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383226/how-do-i-set-the-runtime-classpath-in-eclipse-4-2

Comment: @kshitij, it is not in jar file as i am developing it in eclipse in src folder. I specified following codebase and its says cant load the main class. -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=${workspace_loc:/RMIChatServer/bin/}

Comment: @kshitij, Thanks for the link. It mentioned default classpath. is there something wrong with this path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. i am not sure about that it is right or wrong. because i have not work on RMI

applications. but i am sure that following link solve your problem.

[running rmi server, classnotfound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464687/running-rmi-server-classnotfound)