# How to configure titan over hbase in java eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, hbase, graph-databases, titan

using the following commands as given in the tutorial : 
http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.0/hbase.html

```
 TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.build()
                .set("storage.backend","hbase")
                .open();
```

used the maven dependency :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.thinkaurelius.titan</groupId>
            <artifactId>titan-hbase</artifactId>
            <version>${titan.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Following error is shown

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/MasterNotRunningException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:42)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:479)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:413)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1320)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory$Builder.open(TitanFactory.java:135)
    at pluradj.titan.tinkerpop3.example.JavaExample2.main(JavaExample2.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
```

If possible can you tell the same for cassandra also.

Comment: looks like you are missing this dependency, so you have to tell you how you start your application/code. do you use maven?

Comment: used the dependency <dependency>
 <groupId>com.thinkaurelius.titan</groupId>
 <artifactId>titan-hbase</artifactId>
 <version>0.5.4</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Look here at how to set your runtime classpath in Eclipse: [How do I set the runtime classpath in Eclipse 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383226/how-do-i-set-the-runtime-classpath-in-eclipse-4-2)

It appears your runtime classpath is missing jars due to the NoClassDefFoundError exception.  For this specific error, locate the hbase lib directory from your hbase install and add that to your classpath.

If you use Cassandra, you'll need to set your classpath appropriately for Cassandra.

Titan's HBase client config accepts arbitrary keys from hbase-site.xml
(if it's on the CLASSPATH) and I recommend putting that in your path as well.

Comment: Still not able to get it