# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver even after installing mysql-connector-java-8.0.18

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

So I've been trying to connect this simple database to this java tax program I am working on for school and I can't get the SQL database to connect no matter what I do (using Eclipse IDE). I have the connector installed (mysql-connector-java-8.0.18), but I am still getting the `jdbc.Driver ClassNotFound Exception`. Anyone have any ideas?

```
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // create mysql connection 
            Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306//PersonDB","root","rootroot");  
            Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
```

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Any tips?

Comment: Add the jar from the connector to your [runtime classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10387350/2970947).

Comment: What does "installed" mean? Are the relevant jar files part of your project's Java Build Path?

Comment: Have you set the dependency for you `jar` file in Eclipse ?

Comment: You normally don't 'install' Java libraries, so you need to describe exactly what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Add the jar library manually to the project.

Right Click the project -- > build path -- > configure build path

In Libraries Tab press Add External Jar and Select your jar.

You can find zip for mysql-connector here