# Why I have java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when call PDDocument with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf, pdfbox

Good afternoon. I downloaded all packages from this url https://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi

After that I added all jars as external jars in my Eclipse Mars 2. 0. So now my Java Build Path looks this way (attached file screen).

[image]

But when I run program I have this error 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument

It happens on this line

PDDocument pddDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("C:/Users/miste/Documents/1.pdf"));

As found on internet there is some dependencies, that I’m not included. But I cant imagen what. I added all files from download page. If you can help me, I’ll be glad.

Kind regards, Dmitrii.

Comment: This is an eclipse configuration problem (where sadly I can't help) because you are using the correct libraries (too many of them, btw, but this won't hurt as long it is the same version). Make sure that pdfbox, fontbox and commons-log are available at runtime and not just at build time.

Comment: Can you setup maven as a build tool? This would ensure that everything is available in the correct way. Also you are using a quite old version of eclipse. Try updating to a new one...

Comment: I wonder if it is in Run/Debug settings, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383226

Comment: I downloaded the newest version of eclipse and newest version of Apache Tomcat. Add all dependencies to build path and add all dependencies to Run/Debug (classpath). But still I have the same problem `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument`

Comment: I even build project with Maven, so it added all dependencies
`<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.19</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>`
But still no luck
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument`

Comment: What it can be?